# An inverse problem in PDE cours

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the family of characteristic projections given by
$x(\tau,s)=s\cos(\tau) , Y(\tau,s) = \epsilon s \sin(\tau)$

How do i use the characterist ODE's to show that the quadratic for $Q= x^2+\frac{y^2}{\epsilon^2}$ is conserved.

Currently I have eliminated $\tau$ to a single equation that determin the shape of the curves (ellipse).

I guess knowing how to start would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After time I worked it out. Will leave answer here for the sake of completeness:
It was a lot simpler than I thought:

$Q=x^2+\frac{y^2}{\epsilon^2} = s^2\cos^2(\tau)+ \frac{\epsilon^2 s^2 \sin^2(\tau)}{\epsilon^2}$

$ Q= s^2\cos^2(\tau)+s^2 \sin^2(\tau)$

$\frac{dQ}{d\tau}(s^2\cos^2(\tau)+s^2 \sin^2(\tau)) = -2\sin(\tau)\cos(tau)+2\sin(\tau)cos(\tau)$

Hence $\frac{dQ}{d\tau}=0$  as required.